# What are "Auxilliary nouns" in Kyrgyz?

Tags: parts-of-speech, turkic-languages, relational-nouns

I have heard that the Kyrgyz language has some special words termed "auxilliary nouns" (*жардамчы атоочтор* in Kyrgyz), but I wasn't able to find out what those words are and how they work in that language (searching on Google Scholar gave only a few results in languages like Kyrgyz or Russian that I don't read).

I'd like to see an explanation with some simple glossed examples.

Comment: I believe _атоочтор_ is the wrong term.  In Kyrgyz this refers to [nominals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_(linguistics)) of all kinds.  Could you clarify?  Or provide an example?

Comment: When I first encountered the term *атоочтор* it was used by by Kyrgyz collaborator with reference to the relational nouns described by @Mitzli in the accepted answer. To my confusion my Kyrgyz collaborator later used the same term *атоочтор* to describe some special verb forms (kind of gerunds or participles). "Nominals of all kind" sounds like a good umbrella term for all that things.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I've often seen people less well read in the Kyrgyz grammatical literature call relational nouns _жандоочтор_ ("postpositions"), but most serious Kyrgyz grammars seem to call them _жардамчы атоочтор_ ("‘helping’/auxiliary nominals"), from Кудайбергенов (1980) to Акматалиев et al. (2015).  Even Батманов (1933) calls them nominals (in Russian), though he does discuss them in the postpositions section.

Comment: I proposed an edit to the text of the question incorporating the correct Kyrgyz term.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, "auxiliary noun" is essentially a synonym for "relational noun" ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_noun)). These are basically nouns that can be used to fulfil the role of adpositions, postpositions in the case of Kyrgyz (or Turkish).

An example from Kyrgyz would be:

> Үй ич-ин-де мышык уктап жатат.
>
> house.NOM inside-POSS-LOC cat.NOM sleeping is
>
> 'A cat is sleeping inside the house.'

Comment: Do you know how they are supposed to be different than an object of a preposition in English, other than postposition vs preposition?  (English also has a few postpositions anyway.)

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "an object of a preposition"? Do you mean how are relational nouns different to English compound prepositions containing nouns (like *on **top** of*)?

Comment: Pardon, I had understood that page incorrectly.  But yes, your reformulation is what I should have asked.  *on top of*, *thanks to*, *por medio de*, *внутри*...

Comment: Simple adpositions in English like *from* can't be used as nouns in English but words like *сырт* "outside" in Kyrgyz can be used as plain nouns or in the role of adpositions by adding the genitive and locative suffixes (e.g. *үйдүн сыртында* "outside of the house"). Of course, words like *top* in English can be used as both plain nouns and in compound prepositions.

Comment: I suppose the main in which way in which relational nouns differ from plain nouns used as the object of a preposition is that in English you get a phrase whereas in Kyrgyz you get a whole word. Languages said to have relational nouns also tend to have very few simple adpositions because they mainly rely on case marking which relational nouns supplement (e.g. Turkish) or have no simple adpositions at all (e.g. Classical Nahuatl). In a way, then, the distinct is somewhat arbitrary, though not entirely and the *top* in *on top of* is not so different from the *сырт* in *сыртында*.

Comment: You might also be interested in this question, btw: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/31075/does-swahili-have-relational-nouns (if you haven't already seen it!).

Comment: Re phrase vs whole word, that is because -de (if I can just use Oghuz Turkish) happens to be a suffix/case.  Which is very analogous to the -s in English *besides* (or countless German prepositions) - originally genitive case marking.  I think the only thing I see here is that in some languages some of these phrases are more transparent and analysable, and other phrases in other languages are more opaque and fossilised and would not be produced by the modern grammar.  But that's true for many parts of speech and varies within all languages.

Comment: The fact that *from* cannot stand alone makes it more like -dan.

Answer (score 0):

I am a native speaker of Kyrgyz. I suppose, I can help with some of linguistic issues of the Kyrgyz language.
Sincerely,
Aida.
P.S. In the Kyrgyz language we have Atooch and Atoochtuk, id est Nouns and Verbal Nouns.